# my material or shader Node on the top right bar is gone how do i get it back?

Tags: node-editor

Hi i'm still new to blender and with it's new update things are a little confusing. The little round orange node is gone and I don't know what I did to loose it or how to get it back. I believe it's called the shader or material node. It was there a moment ago but I must've done something to it. Help???

[image]

Comment: It seems you did not select any object which has a material node available. Select an object (maybe the cylinder ?) and you'll see your material. (in the outliner panel of the capture the scene is selected.. so no object with material available)

Comment: click on the material drop down icon next to *new* button below in your screenshot , maybe you disassociated it by mistake

Answer (score 2):

The tabs in the properties window depend on the selected object, to see the materials tab you need to select some object that can have materials applied to it.